# Create XML Pattern PHP Soap Client

Tags: java, php, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to get paninfo from a government provided web service.
Request sample xml for service is as follow.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:pan="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/" xmlns:typ="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/types/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<pan:getPanInfo>
<login>
<typ:userName>xxxxxxxxxx</typ:userName>
<typ:password>xxxxxxxxxx</typ:password>
</login>
<panNo>
<typ:panNo>xxxxxxxxxx</typ:panNo>
</panNo>
</pan:getPanInfo>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have used PHP soap client as follows:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/PanWS.wsdl",array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0,"cache_wsdl" => 0

));

$client->__setLocation("https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/PanWS");

$params = new SoapVar("<login><string:userName>xxxxxxxxx</string:userName><string:password>xxxxxxxxx</string:password></login><panNo><string:panNo>xxxxxxxxxx</string:panNo></panNo>", XSD_ANYXML);
$result = $client->GetPanInfo($params);
```

It generated the following XML pattern

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getPanInfo><login><string:userName>xxxxxxx</string:userName><string:password>xxxxxxx</string:password></login><panNo><string:panNo>xxxxxxx</string:panNo></panNo><panNo/></ns1:getPanInfo></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In response i got 500 internal server error with empty response.

There is same question on stackoverflow but in ruby on rails.
Can any1 help me resolve it in PHP.

> [Savon create matched XML pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568031/savon-create-matched-xml-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The request you send doesn't match the expected format :

- You are missing the types schema import : xmlns:typ="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/types/"
- Your prefix on 'getPanInfo' should be 'pan' and not ns1
- the prefix on username and password is not 'string' but 'typ'
- Same for panNo

Comment: I know !! That is the issue how to set all that things using PHP soap client

Comment: In your soapvar function, you can add the advised modifications. For the schema import, you'll need to add the import in the envelop. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114545/soap-set-proper-xmlns-headers) may help you